# How to move mutliple files from multiple directories to one directory

Tags: find, mv

I have a lot of .iso files in different directories on my computer and I want to move them all at once to some folder. What I would use for searching those file is *find* and *mv* to move it. The obvious way of doing this would be

```
find / -name "*.iso" | mv --target-directory=/home/ISO/
```

but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find / -name "*.iso" -exec mv {} /home/ISO/ \;`

Comment: Wow. That was quick. Thank you, it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
find / -name "*.iso" -exec mv -t /home/ISO/ "{}"  +
```

It will find all files ending with `iso`, and will move them to directory `/home/ISO`.